# Ruby: Query activerecord where length of array column is greater than X

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have this table in my postgres db:

```
  create_table "tracking_infos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "carriers", default: [], array: true
    t.text "tracking_numbers", default: [], array: true
    t.string "order_id"
    t.integer "shop_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_tracking_on_order_id", unique: true
  end
```

And all I'm trying to do is query this table and return records where `tracking_numbers.length` is greater than 1.

I really don't know where to start.. Tried `TrackingInfo.all.pluck(:tracking_numbers)` and then mess around with the returned array. But that's no good.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to use Postgres' `array_length` function ([see docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)):

```rb
TrackingInfo.where("ARRAY_LENGTH(tracking_numbers, 1) > ?", 1).count
```

Bear in mind that the second argument of `ARRAY_LENGTH` represents the dimension of the array (should be 1 in most cases), while the second argument of `where` replaces the `?` placeholder.

Comment: Use `CARDINALITY` instead of `ARRAY_LENGTH` to determine the number of elements in an array so that the shape of the array is ignored.